# How do I find the key from a value in list, from a json file?

Tags: python, json

My solution is below but This was my problem.

I have a json which pairs a school's location with its associated `school-code`. Different school codes may apply to a single location.

```
data = [
   {
    "location": "New York",
    "school-code": "CITYA", 
    "school-code-2": "NYU", 
    "school-code-3": "CityU"
    },
   {
    "location": "New Jersey",
    "school-code": "NJU", 
    "school-code-2": "BOU2", 
    "school-code-3": "NJUE"
   },
   {
    "location": "California",
    "school-code": "CAL",
    "school-code-2": "Cal2"
   },
   {
    "location": "Florida",
    "school-code": "fNJU", 
    "school-code-2": "fNJU2", 
    "school-code-3": "fNJUE"
   }
    ]
```

If the user inputs "CityU" how can I get the location. It should give the location New York.

```
code_input = "CityU" 
print("Your school zone is",location)
output: Your school zone is New York
```

It works with the following code but only if there is an exact match between `school-code` and the user's input:

```
code_input = 'CityU'
school_code = code_input

for i in data:
    if i['school-code-3'] == school_code:
        print(i['location'])

        break
```

I would like if no matter what school code the user enters, it gives the location of that entry.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Many tutorials and other references cover how to iterate through the list, access the dict entry, and compare that value to another value.  We expect you to use these resources, attempt the code ... and then post the problem code if you get stuck.  "How do I implement this feature" is usually off-topic.

Comment: added more info for clarification.

Comment: Yes, you clarified that  you have not yet looked up how to iterated through a dict.  You state that you don't know how to convert a list to a tuple -- another trivial look-up.  We don't know what stops you from achieving the results you want.  You seem to be looking for a way to make a reverse-dictionary ... another search term you can use.

Comment: One hint where you *may* be getting stuck: to make the reverse-dictionary, when you have multiple codes in the list, you probably want to make multiple entries.  This means that you need to iterate through that list.

Comment: Also note that your dict is not uniquely reversible: `GOA` Maps to both CA and NJ.

Comment: I took your suggestion, and modified the data once more removing the lists. Great idea, and perhaps makes it easier to manage. The issue I am facing now,  my code requires the  specific key, that references the value the user referenced.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `next` and a simple generator comprehension:

```
next(d['location'] for d in schools if code_input in d['school-code'])
```

This will raise an error if there are no matches. If this is not desired then you can provide a default return value:

```
next((d['location'] for d in schools if code_input in d['school-code']), None)
```

Comment: interesting.. didnt know next() can be used like that.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
code_input = 'CityU'
l = [i['location'] for i in schools if code_input in i['school-code']][0]
print("Your school zone is",l)
```

```
Your school zone is New York
```

Answer (score 0):

Clunky but this is what I ended up doing, not sure how long this will hold up

```
given_school_code = input("What is your school code? ")

# save the answer to a variable


print(" you entered school code: ", given_school_code)
data = [
       {
        "location": "New York",
        "school-code": "CITY", 
        "school-code-2": "NYU", 
        "school-code-3": "CityU"
        },
       {
        "location": "New Jersey",
        "school-code": "NJU", 
        "school-code-2": "NJU2", 
        "school-code-3": "NJUE"
       },
       {
        "location": "California",
        "school-code": "CAL",
        "school-code-2": "Cal2"
       },
       {
        "location": "Florida",
        "school-code": "fNJU", 
        "school-code-2": "fNJU2", 
        "school-code-3": "fNJUE"
       }
      
    
    ] 


school_code = given_school_code

for i in data:
    try:
        if (school_code == i['school-code']) or (school_code == i['school-code-2']) or  (school_code == i['school-code-3'])  or  (school_code == i['school-code-4']):
            # print(i['location'])
            new_loc = (i['location'])
            print("Your School Zone is", new_loc)
            break
        else:
            print("ah")
    except:
        pass
```

Would be cool if I could get rid of all those `or` statements.